# Is it possible to create a bundle with Rollup that injects HTML from a template?

Tags: html, css, templates, rollup, rollupjs

I'm trying to build a IIFE ([immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)) bundle using `Rollup`.

I would like to bundle all together my JS, CSS, and then some HTML which the Javascript depends on. Check this image to get an idea:

[image]

Is there a way to tell `Rollup` that my input (entry point) is `seguro-vida-hipoteca.js`, and have this file import my SCSS and HTML so it will be automatically injected when somebody uses my library?

That would be, the resulting CSS in the head, and the HTML to some `div` that I would expect to exist in the dom, or just at the end of body.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to tell Rollup that my input (entry point) `is seguro-vida-hipoteca.js`?

Sure, that's what the [`input` option](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#configuration-files) is for.

Injecting Sass in the `head` is easily accomplishable with plugins such as [`rollup-plugin-postcss`](https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss):

```js
// rollup.config.js
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    postcss(),
  ],
}
```

```js
import './style.scss'; // Now each stylesheet you import will
                       // be injected to <head>
```

About injecting/appending html, that is something you would normally do in your code and not through a plugin, although you can take advantage of Rollup to load `template.html` as a string (for example by using [rollup-plugin-html](https://github.com/bdadam/rollup-plugin-html)):

```js
import html from "rollup-plugin-html";

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    html({
      include: "**/*.html",
    }),
  ],
}
```

```js
import template from './template.html';

document.querySelector('#mydiv').innerHTML = template;
```

#### Side note

This seems to be a good use case for [WebComponents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components). More info [here](https://web.dev/web-components-io-2019/).

Comment: Sounds good.. Let me try this some time this weekend and I'll let you know.